# What is the fastest way to download and re-uploading a file in Java?

Tags: java

I want to download and re-upload a file (close to one GB in size) using standard Java API. The current implementation is:

```
private void transfer(String sourceUrl, String targetUrl, long size) throws IOException {
    logger.info("Copying " + sourceUrl + " to " + targetUrl);
    HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL(targetUrl).openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Long.toString(size));
    try (InputStream inputStream = new URL(sourceUrl).openStream();
         OutputStream outputStream = conn.getOutputStream()) {
        byte[] buf = new byte[1 << 20];
        int read;
        long total = 0;
        while ((read = inputStream.read(buf)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(buf, 0, read);
            total += read;
            logger.info(total + "/" + size + " " + (total * 100 / size) + "%");
        }
        outputStream.flush();
    }
}
```

However, it is running slow in comparison with a native application. I tried to increase the buffer size. But it didn't help. What can I do to increase the performance of this method?

Can anyone please help me with a multithreaded example or an NIO example which can improve the performance?

Comment: I will caution you strongly against multi-threading, unless you have a way to ensure that pieces that arrive out of order are dealt with accordingly.

Comment: try doing a run without the logger, I have seen many times that the logger is actually the source of the slowdown